# How to find the value and id of select drop-down which has been created dynamically and which is present within the another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dynamic-programming

I trying to create a rectangle dynamically using the jquery and after creating the rectangle I am appending a `select drop-down` to it both of which are done dynamically and `id` is assigned to them dynamically. After creating all the required rectangles when I submit the data then I would like to read each of the rectangles and the value of `select` for each that rectangle. I am able to get the `id` of the rectangle but I am unable to get the `selected` value and `id` of select dropdown for each of them. I tried a few things but none worked hence posting the same here:

`function to create the replica of the rectangle and append select drop-down`:

```
$('#DroppableCanvas').on('drop',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data    =   event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.setAttribute("id", 'box'+NewBoxId);
    nodeCopy.classList.add('draggableAddedFields');
    nodeCopy.setAttribute("draggable",true);
    
    var SelectID        =   'select'+NewBoxId;
    var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("id", SelectID).attr("name", SelectID);
    
    $.each(BusinessStep, function (i, el) {
        combo.append("<option>" + el.text + "</option>");
    });
    
    $(nodeCopy).append(combo);
    
    event.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    NewBoxId++;
});
```

`function to read each rectangle and all the added elements within each rectangle`:

```
//After adding all the drag and drop fields with values submit them
$('#SubmitFields').on('click',function(){
    var AllFields       =   [];
    $(".draggableAddedFields").each(function() {
        var obj     =   new Object();
        obj.ID      =   this.id;
        console.log($(this.id).find("select"));
        AllFields.push(obj);
    });
})
```

I am getting the `jQuery` functions when I try to do:
`console.log($(this.id).find("select"));`

I get undefined when I try to do:
`console.log($(this.id).find("select").attr('id'));`

I would like to find each element for example here in this case `select` element `id` and choose `value` for the select dropdown.

Since `$(this.id)` belongs to the outer rectangle I am not able to get value using this. In most of the responses, I searched they have straight forward requirement but in my case, it seems a bit different hence posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find any element inside the current one, use `$(this).find` instead of `$(this.id).find`

For getting the id and value of select dropdown inside `draggableAddedFields`, use this

```
$(".draggableAddedFields").each(function() {
       var selectId =    $(this).find("select").attr('id')
       var selectValue = $(this).find("select").val()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro. I knew I was doing a small mistake. My brain completely stopped working after spending more than an hour hence I thought of posting it. I should have tried with the whole element not bypassing just the id `$(this.id).find("select")`.